# How to align a custom menu made from TImage controls so it can stretch correctly to various resolutions?

Tags: delphi, menu

[image: Menu picture]

I have this custom menu I made with `TImage` controls, but I am having trouble to stretch it according to a given phone resolution. I am new to Delphi and I cannot find any similar tutorial.

Comment: Don't stretch the images, use separate images of different sizes for the various resolutions. You can query the screen size at runtime and then load the most appropriate sized images as needed. Or, if you are using FMX, you can create [different Views](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_FireMonkey_Views) for the various resolutions, and then display a different sized menu on each View.

Comment: FMX Imagelists exist specifically for this purpose.